# Jquery tools tooltip misplaced

Tags: html, css, tooltip, jquery-tools

I am facing an issue with Jquery Tools Tooltip.
You can see on : http://www.toulousehoopsummit.com/l-ecole-en-basket

The 3 pictures at the bottom have a tooltip.
In IE9 and FF12, the tooltips are too much on the right.
In Safari, it is correctly located.

I had to add
`offset: [0, -450]`
to fix the problem on IE and FF but Safari users face now the inverse issue.

Do you have any idea why I get this and how I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In chrome they are too much on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) - this has saved my projects many times.

Just put the JS file in, and your `<html>` will have added css selectors such as `.ie`  `.safari3` etc without having to actually debug the jQuery Tools Tooltip.

It will let you tweak your CSS according to browser version and OS.

Comment if you need any help with this!

Comment: Even if it's a hack and I'm not a real fan of this kind of trick, this is the only solution that could make it work on my iPhone and iPad. Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version:
http://pastehtml.com/view/bymzdgvhv.html

This works for me correctly in all browsers.

Comment: They are for me in exact position in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to new ideas and some good looking plugins, you should try:

[TipTip jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin)

I've been using it for some time and its awesome!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to get rid of Jquery tools.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on an iPad now, so I can't really test this out. 
But why don't you just fetch the top and left positions of the images using jquery, and offset the tooltips positions compared to the images positions?

Comment: Why don't we get rid of jQuery and it's plugins ? Why don't we recoode everything manually ? Why don't we reinvent the wheel ? Come on...